# How to get substring after next ':' after a slice?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this:

```
var string = 'foo:bar:1234:something:4321';
```

I want to return the section after `bar:` up until the next `:`. In this case I want "1234". The size can vary.

Here's what I have started, but am unsure how to specify the ending.

```
var newString = string.slice('bar:'.indexOf(), <HOW TO SPECIFY THE END?>);
```

**EDIT**

The string could also contain more values and colons so these are possible too:

```
var string = 'fu:bu:foo:bar:1234:something:4321';
var string = 'bar:1234:something:4321';
```

Comment: `string.split(':')[2]`

Comment: I’d say, split it simply at `:`, and loop through the results until you find the value `bar` – the next element is the one you want.

Comment: @Papa See updated question. Unfortunately it's not necessarily that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getBarValue(str) {
    var splitString = str.split('bar:'); // make this `:bar:` if foobar: is an issue

    if (splitString.length < 2) {
        return null; // "bar:" does not exist in string
    }

    return splitString[1].substring(0, splitString[1].indexOf(':'));
}

var barVal = getBarValue('foo:bar:1234:something:4321');
console.log(barVal);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a regex:

```
// catch `bar:` at the beginning of the string, or
// :bar: elsewhere
var matches = string.match(/(?:^|:)bar:([^:]+):/);

var newString = matches[1];
```

```js
var string = 'foo:bar:1234:something:4321';

var matches = string.match(/(?:^|:)bar:([^:]+):/);

var newString = matches[1];

console.log(newString);

string = 'bar:1234:something:4321';

console.log(newString);
```

Comment: And now you have two problems :)

Comment: I might have to use a regex, but i was really hoping for a non-regex solution if possible. I hate working with regex and can never read them later on.

Comment: @Catfish Fair enough. But if you wanted a solution that doesn't involve creating and throwing away an array every time (and perhaps looping through it, as well), here you go.

Comment: @Paul, you don't have to create an array if you only locate the first instance of `"bar:"` then match until the next instance of `':'`. I'm always surprised regexes are so often preferred to simple `indexOf()`/`substr()` strategies.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi  and if `foobar:` is present in the string before `bar:`?

Comment: @Paul, *I want to return the section after `bar:` up until the next `:`* does not say anything about that, and *the string could also contain more values and colons so these are possible too* does not provide counter-examples, so outside of perimeter, and YAGNI.